# Well-defined generating function for the Legendre polynomials

Tags: complex-numbers, generating-functions

For the Legendre polynomials $P_n$ of degree $n$, normed to $P_n(1)=1$, i [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Legendre_polynomials_in_multipole_expansions) the following formula for its generating function:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P_n(x) z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xz+z^2}},
\end{equation}
for $x \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|z|<1$.

Since $|z|<1$, we already know that
\begin{equation}
1-2xz+z^2 \neq 0.
\end{equation}
But i still have a problem with the square root expression, since for complex valued arguments, it is not clear *which* of the two possible square roots we should take here.

Does anyone know how to interpret this expression?

Answer (score 0):

This polynomials are defined for $|x| \le 1$, and in this case $1 - 2xz  + z^2 \ge 0$. To give you an idea, call $x = \cos\theta$, this is always possible because $|x| \le 1$. Therefore

$$
1 -2xz + z^2 = 1 - 2z \cos\theta + z^2 = |\mathbf{e} - \mathbf{z}|^2 \ge 0
$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{z}$ and the unit vector $\mathbf{e}$. The root $(1 - 2xz + z^2)^{1/2}$ then takes only real values

Comment: I don't really understand your argument. If i take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=\frac{i}{2}$, then $1-2xz+z^2 = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2}i$, i.e. a complex valued number. How do you take a real valued root from it?

Comment: @Simul My apologies, I think I misunderstood your question the first time. There's no problem with the generating function, if $w = 1 - 2xz + z^2 $ just take the principal argument of $w$ and half it